# how to pass url pathvariable in axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

**this is userAction code (redux).**

```
export const logoutUser = (email) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    
     const e_mail = JSON.stringify(email) 
     console.log("email",e_mail)  //prints email "xyz@gmail.com"
     const url = `/http://localhost:8080/logout/${e_mail}`;
    
    

    // const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/logout",email); i get 400 error if i use this.
   const res= getPost(url).then((res)=>{
      console.log("response", res);
    }).catch((err)=>{
      console.error(err);
    })
    dispatch({
      type: actionTypes.USER_LOGOUT,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({ type: actionTypes.USER_REGISTER_FAIL, payload: err });
  }
};
export const getPost = async(funcParamURL) => {
  const res= await axios.get(`${funcParamURL}`);
   return res;
 }
```

** logout link**

```
 <Link onClick={handleSubmit} style={{display: userIsLoggedIn?"block":"none"}} className="nav-link" to="/">logout</Link>
```

**handle submit func**

```
const handleSubmit =()=>{
let email = user.email
         logoutUser(email);
    }
```

now it gives me 404 error *http://localhost:3000/http://localhost:8080/logout/%22hsekol1025@gmail.com%22 404 (Not Found)*
i think i should only pass my email as **http://localhost:3000/http://localhost:8080/logout/hsekol1025@gmail.com** i did this in postman and it worked fine.what should i do in front end to pass the email as url pathvariable using axios.thankyou

Comment: Try `const url = \`http://localhost:8080/logout/${encodeURIComponent(email)}\``. Your main issue was having a `/` at the start of your URL. The way to make values safe for use within URLs is via [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), not `JSON.stringify()`. The latter will wrap string values in `"` characters which is probably not what you want

Comment: May this help you If not please tell https://stackoverflow.com/a/51845501/13018498

Comment: @BinilGeorge doesn't seem appropriate at all

Comment: this const url = `http://localhost:8080/logout/${encodeURIComponent(email)}` output is like http://localhost:8080/logout/hsekol1025%40gmail.com here instead of @ its taking %40 so it fails.

Comment: its works fine with encodeURI(email)  thank you @Phil

Comment: `%40` is the correct sequence to use to represent `@` in a URL. If it doesn't work, then your server-side process running on port 8080 is broken